# How to add custom block to existing tab of product at admin side

Tags: magento2

I want to add custom messages to my custom created attributes on the product page by using `Block` and `Phtml`.
My problem can be illustrated as following:
[image]

Comment: you mean cms block? that would be super hacky. I do not recommend this

Comment: I just need to show a dynamic message using phtml after my Custom Attribute field.
Please tell me the recommendation to achieve this.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic?

Comment: Dynamic means if the current value is available then the message will show otherwise the message will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken you can achieve it by adding custom input type in a module

first we need to add install script
Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php :

```
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;


    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'attribute_id',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\CustomField',
                'label' => 'Custom attribute',
                'input' => 'text',
                'class' => '',
                'source' => '',
                'global' => 0,
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => null,
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                'unique' => false,
                'apply_to' => '',
                'system' => 1,
                'group' => 'General',
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

next we need to create our renderer for custom input:
Vendor/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Product/CustomField.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product;


use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement;

class CustomField extends Field
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function render(AbstractElement $element)
    {
        $html = '';
        // you can modify your html output as you see fit. probably will work with parent::_decorateRowHtml but here you can see exactly how it's done.
        return $this->_decorateRowHtml($element, $html);
    }

    public function _decorateRowHtml($element, $html){
        return '<tr id="row_' . $element->getHtmlId() . '">' . $html . '</tr>';
    }
}
```

with this you can add javascript to watch for input change and if you need that text is loaded dynamic then you will need to add route and call your url.

Vendor/Module/etc/Adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="customattribute" frontName="customattribute">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Adminhtml" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

now we need to add controller:
Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Catalog/Product/Dynamic.php

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Catalog\Product;

class Dynamic extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute(){
       // do what is needed and output your html with echo
    }
}
```

so if you need to call your url you can add following to render function CustomField.php:

```
$html.="<script>
require([
    'jquery',
    'prototype',
], function(jQuery){
    function do_something() {

        new Ajax.Request('".$this->getUrl('customattribute/catalog/product/dynamic')."', {
            loaderArea:     true,
            asynchronous:   true,
            parameters:     params,
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
               //do something with output
               return true;
            }
        });
    }

    jQuery('my_input').change(function () {
        do_something();
    });
});
</script>";
```